# Rotating line in Python,Tkinter

Tags: python, rotation, tkinter, line

I have one not so complicated question,but i can not figure it out.I would like to draw a set of line (not polygon,it can be opened on each side),and i would like to rotate line.Something like when your using turtle and then order to to turn left or right for a given number of degrees,but in Tkinter.I do not know the points,so I could compute it using trig functions.I mean,I do know them,but I was wondering is there any simpler way than that in Tkinter?I havent wrote any code,because there isnt much to write:create canvas,create line and that it.Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M10) (upon which Tkinter is based):

> Individual items may be moved or scaled using widget commands
>   described below, but they may not be rotated.

If you want to rotate a line, you'll have to do the math on the endpoints of the lines.

Comment: Ok,thanks...not what I was hoping for but thats Tkinters creator fault :)

Comment: I gave it some thinking and realised that my question hasnt been clear.I dont really have to rotate line,and thats not what im really interested in....What I really wanted to ask is there a way for me to assign line length and assign its angle relative to previously drawn line?

Comment: I would mention the `Canvas.coords(item, ...)` method for "rotating" existing lines (trigonometry / vector algebra is left to the Reader).